# time.mktime(datetime.timetuple()) seems behaving incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pytz

Hi I have time converted into gmt as below
2016-11-18 13:00:00+00:00
I want to convert this into millis which I am doing as below

```
epoch = int(time.mktime(datetime_in_gmt.timetuple()))

>>>print(epoch)
1479454200
```

and then when I do use this link http://www.epochconverter.com/ and paste this epoch i.e 1479454200 I get the result as

GMT: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 07:30:00 GMT
Your time zone: Friday 18 November 2016 01:00:00 PM IST GMT+5:30

I am not getting as why I am getting 18 Nov 7.30 as GMT because my GMT time was 2016-11-18 13:00:00+00:00 ?
any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of timetuple use timestamp.
Something like
int(datetime_in_gmt.timestamp()) * 1000